# ide-helper does not work in PhpStorm when working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I work with Laravel 5.3, use `barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper`.

I've generated `.phpstorm.meta.php` and `_ide_helper.php`, but still marks PhpStorm classes like undefined.

What can I do with this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE -- may help.

Comment: File->Invalidate Cache did not help

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the **single classes** instead of of the full qualified paths.

So change your imports from
`use Illuminate\Http\Request` to `use Request`

Also consider to install the "Laravel" plugin for PHPStorm. You can find it by browsing in the JetBrains plugin repository (can be found in the settings).

Before (re)generating your ide-helper files, try the following commands:
`composer dumpauto`
`php artisan config:clear`
`php artisan clear-compiled`

[image: As you can see here]

Comment: Your suggestion does not work. PHPStorm marks like undefined not only classes. Helpers like config(), route(), trans() marked like undefined too. Laravel plugin was install.

Comment: Tried to invalidate cache? @J.Menshov

Comment: Done [link](http://take.ms/lKyre), but unfortunately did not help. [link](http://take.ms/wVS6A) @manniL